# Page replication error in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I built one code to download the entire page as HTML with Jsoup. The download part is working as expected. But my problem is - **The page is being replicated more than once in the browser when I open the downloaded file and I don't know whats going wrong**. Check out the code below:

```
public class httptest {

    static File file;
    String crawlingNode;
    static BufferedWriter writer = null;
    static httptest ht;

    public httptest() throws IOException{

            file = new File(//***SET HERE YOUR TEST PATH***);   

    }

    private void GetLinks() throws IOException{

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=mamamia")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .get();

        Elements links = doc.select("*");
            String crawlingNode = links.html();
                System.out.println(crawlingNode);
                    httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);

    }


       private static void OpenWriter(File file){
           try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to open URL Writer");
                e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }

       private static void WriteOnFile(BufferedWriter writer, String crawlingNode){

           try {

                writer.write(crawlingNode);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to write URL Node");
                e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }


       private static void CloseWriter(BufferedWriter writer){
           try {

                writer.close();

           } catch (IOException e) {

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to close URL Writer");
                System.err.println(e);

           }
       }

       public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

            ht = new httptest();
            httptest.OpenWriter(file);
            ht.GetLinks();
            httptest.CloseWriter(writer);

    }

}
```

Some parts of the code might seems weird but remember that this is the SSCCE code version. Any ideas of what might be helpfull please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
Elements links = doc.select("*");
    String crawlingNode = links.html();
        System.out.println(crawlingNode);
            httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);
```

use:

```
  Element links = doc.select("*").first();
            String crawlingNode = links.html();
                System.out.println(crawlingNode);
                    httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);
```

I think the Elements type is more complex and detailed to use. I found this code change analysing this source: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Anyway, this solution worked out for me.